# Not able to upload the files

Tags: java, jsp

I am using UploadServlet program of file uploading which is readymade on Net..and in jsp i m using 4 textboxes with 4 input files tags fields. As i want only to upload those files to the server which are checked by checkbox so i am validating checkboxes wheather they are cheked or not.
So i am trying to get the value of the checkboxes using `request.getParamterValues()`.
But since enctype is present in my jsp so null value getting.I used annotaion `@MultipartConfig` bt still i m geting `NullPointerException` in the program.
Any solution for this,..I have putted `servlet-api-3.0` in `WEB-INF/lib/` folder also.